# SQL method to replace repeating blanks with single blanks

Tags: sql

Is there a more elegant way of doing this. I want to replace repeating blanks with single blanks....

```
   declare @i int

    set @i=0
    while @i <= 20
    begin
        update myTable
        set myTextColumn = replace(myTextColumn, '  ', ' ')
        set @i=@i+1
    end
```

(its sql server 2000 - but I would prefer generic SQL)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a simple set based way that will collapse multiple spaces into a single space by applying three replaces.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (myTextColumn VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('0Space')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (' 1 Spaces 1 Spaces. ')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('  2  Spaces  2  Spaces.  ')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('   3   Spaces  3   Spaces.   ')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('    4    Spaces  4    Spaces.    ')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('     5     Spaces  5     Spaces.     ')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('      6      Spaces  6      Spaces.      ')

select replace(
          replace(
             replace(
                LTrim(RTrim(myTextColumn)), ---Trim the field
             '  ',' |'),                    ---Mark double spaces
          '| ',''),                         ---Delete double spaces offset by 1
       '|','')                              ---Tidy up
       AS SingleSpaceTextColumn
 from @myTable
```

Your Update statement can now be set based:

```
 update @myTable
    set myTextColumn = replace(
                          replace(
                             replace(
                                LTrim(RTrim(myTextColumn)),
                             '  ',' |'),
                          '| ',''),
                       '|','')
```

Use an appropriate Where clause to limit the Update to only the rows that have you need to update or maybe have double spaces.

Example:

```
where 1<=Patindex('%  %', myTextColumn)
```

I have found an external write up on this method: [REPLACE Multiple Spaces with One](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/)

Comment: I think this is the same as Paul's answer, but your comments make it a bit more readable

Comment: Well spotted they are the same method.

Comment: External Reference clarified things

Comment: I agree it is better worded and better understandable but somehow it feels like taking credit for someone else's work. Paul's answer is exactly the same.

Comment: @Lieven : I made the decision based on reading the external reference Andrew cited above.

Comment: This assumes that your text does not have the symbol '|' in it.

This is a very good thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql

Answer (score 29):

This works:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myTextColumn =
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(myTextColumn
                ,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) -- CHAR(1) is unlikely to appear
        ,CHAR(1)+' ','')
    ,CHAR(1),'')
WHERE myTextColumn LIKE '%  %'
```

Entirely set-based; no loops.

So we replace any two spaces with an unusual character and a space. If we call the unusual character X, 5 spaces become: ' X X ' and 6 spaces become ' X X X'. Then we replace 'X ' with the empty string. So 5 spaces become ' ' and 6 spaces become ' X'. Then, in case there was an even number of spaces, we remove any remaining 'X's, leaving a single space.

Comment: Technically, true. But technically pretty much any SQL will involve a loop. I should have said it uses a single query.

Comment: Cleverly avoids looping round the table. I wonder if it could be made any more readable though

Comment: If it were me, I'd hide it away in a function. Then you'd have UPDATE myTable SET myTextColumn = dbo.ReduceSpaces(myColumnText) WHERE... and then you can put whatever explanatory text in the function.

Comment: But as we all know (I hope), scalar functions cannot be optimised, so we all avoid them (I hope!)

Comment: hehe...well it depends a bit on what you're using them for.

Answer (score 6):

```
select 
    string = replace(
                replace(
                    replace(' select   single       spaces',' ','<>')
                    ,'><','')
                ,'<>',' ')
```

[Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql/2455869#2455869)

Answer (score 3):

Not very SET Based but a simple `WHILE` would do the trick.

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable (myTextColumn VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('NoSpace')
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('One Space')
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('Two  Spaces')
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('Multiple    Spaces    .')

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #myTable WHERE myTextColumn LIKE '%  %')
  UPDATE  #myTable 
  SET     myTextColumn = REPLACE(myTextColumn, '  ', ' ') 
  WHERE   myTextColumn LIKE '%  %'

SELECT * FROM #myTable

DROP TABLE #myTable
```

Comment: Of course, this won't work on SQL Server 2000 because of the `OUTPUT` clause, but good answer.

Comment: @Codesleuth - thanks, I missed that requirement. The answer has been updated to work with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: aww, but you changed it to a temp table? That makes me sad, declared tables work in 2000 too you know!

Comment: @Codesleuth - lol, no I didn't know. All SQL Server 2000 knowledge is burried in the darkest corners of my head and then some. OP can always take the original version then and just remove the OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 'starting...' --sets @@rowcount
WHILE @@rowcount <> 0
    update myTable
    set myTextColumn = replace(myTextColumn, '  ', ' ')
    where myTextColumn like '%  %'
```

Answer (score 2):

Step through the characters one by one, and maintain a record of the previous character.  If the current character is a space, and the last character is a space, `stuff` it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemoveExtraSpaces]  (@Number AS varchar(1000))
Returns Varchar(1000)
As
Begin
Declare @n int  -- Length of counter
Declare @old char(1)

Set @n = 1
--Begin Loop of field value
While @n <=Len (@Number)
    BEGIN
     If Substring(@Number, @n, 1) = ' ' AND @old = ' '
      BEGIN
        Select @Number = Stuff( @Number , @n , 1 , '' )
      END
     Else
      BEGIN
       SET @old = Substring(@Number, @n, 1)
       Set @n = @n + 1
      END
    END
Return @number
END
GO


select [dbo].[fnRemoveExtraSpaces]('xxx     xxx     xxx    xxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Simplest solution :)

```
    update myTable
    set myTextColumn = replace(replace(replace(LTrim(RTrim(myTextColumn )),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table blank(
field_blank char(100))

insert into blank values('yyy      yyyy')
insert into blank values('xxxx    xxxx')
insert into blank values ('xxx    xxx')
insert into blank values ('zzzzzz zzzzz')

update blank 
set field_blank = substring(field_blank,1,charindex(' ',field_blank)-1) + ' ' + ltrim(substring(field_blank,charindex(' ',field_blank) + 1,len(field_blank)))
where CHARINDEX (' ' , rtrim(field_blank)) > 1

select * from blank
```

Comment: @ck: I am interested to see loop in sql. Can you please post as update to your answer. tia.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above examples almost did a trick but I needed something that was more stable and independent of the table or column or a set number of iterations. So this is my modification from most of the above queries.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfReplaceAll 
(
    @OriginalText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @OldText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @NewText NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (@OriginalText LIKE '%' + @OldText + '%')
    BEGIN
        SET @OriginalText = REPLACE(@OriginalText,@OldText,@NewText)
    END

    RETURN @OriginalText
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, your Data like this

```
Table name : userdata Field: id, comment, status, 

 id,  "I love -- -- - -spaces  -- -    my INDIA" , "Active" <br>
 id,  "I love -- -- - -spaces  -- -    my INDIA" , "Active" <br>
 id,  "I love -- -- - -spaces  -- -    my INDIA" , "Active" <br>
 id,  "I love -- -- - -spaces  -- -    my INDIA" , "Active" <br>
```

So just do like this

```
update userdata set comment=REPLACE(REPLACE(comment," ","-SPACEHERE-"),"-SPACEHERE"," ");
```

I didn't tested , but i think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Ships
SET name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '  ', ' ' + CHAR(1)), CHAR(1) + ' ', ''), CHAR(1), '')
WHERE name LIKE '%  %'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myTextColumn,' ',' %'),'% ',''),'%','')
```

Statement above worked terrifically for replacing multiple spaces with a single space. Optionally add `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to remove spaces at the beginning.

Got it from here: http://burnignorance.com/database-tips-and-tricks/remove-multiple-spaces-from-a-string-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE
 (SELECT count(myIDcolumn) 
  from myTable where myTextColumn like '%  %') > 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE myTable 
  SET myTextColumn = REPLACE(myTextColumn ,'  ',' ')
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REM_SPACES (TEXTO VARCHAR(2000))

    RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)

    LANGUAGE SQL

    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    SET TEXTO = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(TEXTO)));

    WHILE LOCATE('  ',TEXTO,1) >= 1 DO
        SET TEXTO = REPLACE(TEXTO,'  ',' ');
    END WHILE;

RETURN TEXTO;

END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Update myTable set myTextColumn = replace(myTextColumn, '  ', ' ');
```

The above query will remove all the double blank spaces with single blank space

But this would work only once.

Comment: @cjk it's clearly mentioned in the answer, it would work only once.

Comment: And it is clearly mentioned in the question that the OP wants to replace REPEATING spaces with a single space.  The example in the question even has the SQL in it that you posted as an answer, and she has a loop (WHILE) to perform the double-to-single replacement repeatedly.  BTW, I did NOT down vote.