# Remove Duplicate Space Half of String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove duplicate spaces in a string and leave only one, identical to function trim Excel. How to do this in sql?

Comment: Use `ltrim(rtrim(col))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)

Comment: Trim removes leading/trailing spaces.  Not necessarily duplicated spaces.  Do you want to trim a string or remove mid string duplicates?

Comment: try: `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('some   string    with         many     spaces'
  , '  ', ' ' + CHAR(7)), CHAR(7) + ' ', ''), CHAR(7), '') AS NewStr`

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @spaces varchar(100) = 'String     With Spaces'

SELECT REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                LTRIM(RTRIM(@spaces))
            ,'  ', ' ' + CHAR(100)) 
          ,CHAR(100) + ' ', '')
       ,CHAR(100), '') AS Result
```