# SQL Server - replace multiple apostrophes with single apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server

On my database I have had an issue with how I have escaped single quotes, resulting in them being doubled up every time a record is saved.   I have fixed this now, but I need to clean up the mess it has created.

So I was wondering what's the most straight forward to replace all instances of more than on apostrophe with a single one.   So for example replace ''''''' with '

There are many instances of varying numbers of them in the table.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this trick below

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET columnName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(columnName,'''','<>'),'><',''),'<>','''')
```

This trick comes in handy for replacing any character's multiple consecutive instances with corresponding single instance. I found this on [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql) for replacing multiple instance of space characters with single space .

Comment: Very dangerous. At least use a control character as a substitute.

Answer (score 2):

This involves lots of single quotes:

```
update t
     set col = replace(col, '''''', '''');
-----------------------------^^**    ^^
```

The first string of single quotes has six single quotes, the second has four.

The `^^` and `**` show the doubled single quotes that represent a single quote.

Comment: Thanks but this would only work for that specific number of quotes ?  I want a solution that will replace all instances.   So for example both ''' and '''''''' would be replaced with a single quote.

Comment: I think this will replace any number of occurences that have 2 singel quotes. The replace function finds the first 2, replaces it with one, than finds the next 2, and so on...

Comment: @Brian . . . I guess when I've faced this problem with single quotes, it has only been two in a row.  mhasan's solution works for any number.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion anyway Gordon.