# How to remove the space(more the two space) between two word in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @var nvarchar(500)='Software    Development'
select @var as NotTrim
select LTRIM(RTRIM(@var)) as Trim
```

Expecting output is "Software Development"(With single between two words)

[image]

Comment: I think `REPLACE` may be needed??

Comment: https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(500)='Software              Development'
SELECT @var AS NotTrim
SELECT Trimmed = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes.Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  s,
  LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s,' ',' ^'),'^ ',''),'^','')))
FROM (SELECT '   Q  W       E   ' s) q
```

`^` - you can use any symbol which isn't contained in your string.
This method I found on forum `sql.ru`.

This method replaces any count of spaces to one space. I used this method many times and I think it works well.

Your example

```
declare @var nvarchar(500)='Software    Development'
select @var as NotTrim
select LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,' ',' ^'),'^ ',''),'^',''))) as Trim
```

You can see how it works step by step

```
SELECT
  s,
  -- step 1 - add special char before to each spaces
  REPLACE(s,' ',' ^'),
  -- step 2 - delete special char and space after this special char
  REPLACE(REPLACE(s,' ',' ^'),'^ ',''),
  -- step 3 - delete special chars
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s,' ',' ^'),'^ ',''),'^',''),
  -- step 4 - delete start and end spaces if you need it
  LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(s,' ',' ^'),'^ ',''),'^','')))
FROM (SELECT '   Q  W       E   ' s) q
```

Comment: Yes I tried.Its working