# SQL server 2012 - convert sales order line data for knime market basket analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, knime

I am trying to read a table in knime for market basket analysis. To do that I need sales order line data from SQL server 2012 in this format: A single column with space concatenated items.
Example:

```
ordNo itemNo
x     a1
x     c2
y     a1
y     b4
y     r1
```

to the following:

```
col0
a1 c2
a1 b4 r1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML` clause :

```
select distinct stuff ((select distinct ' '+ t1.itemno
                        from table t1
                        where t1.ordno = t.ordno
                        for xml path('')
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                      ) as [col0]
from table t;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. It's a bit slow but I expected that.

Comment: I also used select string = replace(replace(replace(' select   single       spaces',' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql to remove the excess spaces.