# Mysql Trim not working for all values of specific column

Tags: mysql

I have one table with some values stored in keyword column, but values inside keyword column contain extra space while retrieving the data query is not fetching all records due to this extra space I tried using trim() in mysql  but it didn't work for me

Expected output: mysql query should get all records by avoiding extra space following where condition.

Table:

```
id  keyword    
1   some text for product  //here  single  space after 'some'
2   some   text for product  // here two space after 'some'
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where trim(keyword)='some text for product'
```

After performing above query will return only single record not all records because of extra spaces in column values.

Comment: trim would only remove leading and trailing characters defailt is space. and i don_'t know what do you expect from trim(keyword) = "some text for product'  a keyword nother can be equal to a a text with some words.

Comment: actually i want to get all   values from keyword  column but it contain  extra space  so where query is not working

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample ..  and the expected  result

Comment: search for sql replace spaces eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql , even though for sql server easily adapted for mysql..

Comment: Is there a (good) reason that your data contains a double space? Otherwise make sure your data is stored in a proper way (e.g. remove the double spaces before you store them). Storing invalid/useless/suboptimal data is a cause for a lot of headache. You may also want to look into fulltext search, it will allow you some leniency when searching random text in random text (e.g. spaces, points, word orders, ...) and may (or may not) work too.

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM()` removes spaces at the beginning or the end of the string. You basically want to replace double spaces *within the string* with single spaces. You can use `REPLACE()` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE REPLACE(keyword, '  ', ' ') = 'some text for product'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmkU3JmvEQeaf54AMsLmgh/0)**:

```
WITH `table` AS (
      SELECT 'some text for product' keyword
      UNION ALL SELECT 'some  text for product' keyword
)
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE REPLACE(keyword, '  ', ' ') = 'some text for product';

| keyword                |
| ---------------------- |
| some text for product  |
| some  text for product |
```

Comment: @MSP: I added a db fiddle to my answer; this works fine for the sample data that you provided.