# How to replace multiple occurrence of comma in a single comma between two substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have one input string *'abcdefg,,,,,,,ghijk,,,,,lmno'*
and we want an output of *'abcdefg,ghijk,lmno'* in SQL Server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql) you can replace multiple `,` with a single `,` like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('abcdefg,,,,,,,ghijk,,,,,lmno', ',', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ',')
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24669d3ed32308af6b77679a6c9151b8)