# What is regexp_replace equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, oracle

I have this piece of code in Oracle which I need to convert into SQL Server to get the same behavior. I have used the `REPLACE` function. It seems to be working but I just wanted to make sure.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
                phonenumber, 
               '([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{4})', 
               '(\1)\2-\3'
               ) phonenumber
```

Comment: The REPLACE function in SQL Server definitely wont work for that

Comment: @MartinSmith any suggestions

Comment: So you are looking for strings matching exactly 10 digits and trying to convert them to `(012)345-6789`?

Comment: If you need actual REGEX support in SQL Server, you need to implement CLR functions.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. so basically, for example, I have phone number xxx- xxx xxxx and I wanted to formate it like (xxx) xxx- xxxx

Answer (score 9):

As Martin said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61488652/577765), SQL Server does not have built-in RegEx functionality (and while it has not been suggested here, just to be clear: no, the `[...]` wildcard of `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` is *not* RegEx). If your data has little to no variation then yes, you can use some combination of T-SQL functions: `REPLACE`, `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `CHARINDEX`, `PATINDEX`, `FORMATMESSAGE`, `CONCAT`, and maybe one or two others.

However, if the data / input has even a moderate level of complexity, then the built-in T-SQL functions will be at best be cumbersome, and at worst useless. In such cases it's possible to do actual RegEx via SQLCLR (as long as you aren't using Azure SQL Database Single DB or SQL Server 2017+ via AWS RDS), which is (restricted) .NET code running within SQL Server. You can either code your own / find examples here on S.O. or elsewhere, or try a pre-done library such as the one I created, [SQL# (SQLsharp)](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_66110857), the Free version of which contains several RegEx functions. Please note that SQLCLR, being .NET, is not a POSIX-based RegEx, and hence does not use [POSIX character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) (meaning: you will need to use `\d` for "digits" instead of `[:digit:]`).

The level of complexity needed in this particular situation is unclear as the example code in the question implies that the data is simple and uniform (i.e. `1112223333`) but the example data shown in a [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61488458/577765#comment108773031_61488458) appears to indicate that there might be dashes and/or spaces in the data (i.e. `xxx- xxx xxxx`).

If the data truly is uniform, then stick with the pure T-SQL solution provided by @MartinSmith. But, if the data is of sufficient complexity, then please consider the RegEx example below, using a SQLCLR function found in the Free version of my [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_66110857) library (as mentioned earlier), that easily handles the 3 variations of input data and more:

```sql
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(tmp.phone,
                            N'\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]*(\d{3})[ .-]*(\d{4})', N'($1)$2-$3',
                            -1,   -- count (-1 == unlimited)
                            1,    -- start at
                            N'')  -- RegEx options
FROM   (VALUES (N'8885551212'),
               (N'123- 456 7890'),
               (N'(777) 555- 4653')
       ) tmp([phone]);
```

returns:

```
(888)555-1212
(123)456-7890
(777)555-4653
```

The RegEx pattern allows for:

- 0 or 1 `(`
- 3 decimal digits
- 0 or 1 `)`
- 0 or more of  , `.`, or `-`
- 3 decimal digits
- 0 or more of  , `.`, or `-`
- 4 decimal digits

---

**NOTE**

It was mentioned that the newer Language Extensions might be a better choice than SQLCLR. Language Extensions allow calling R / Python / Java code, hosted outside of SQL Server, via the `sp_execute_external_script` stored procedure. As the [Tutorial: Search for a string using regular expressions (regex) in Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/tutorials/search-for-string-using-regular-expressions-in-java) page shows, external scripts are actually *not* a good choice for many / most uses of RegEx in SQL Server. The main problems are:

1. Unlike with SQLCLR, the only interface for external scripts is a stored procedure. This means that you can't use any of that functionality inline in a query (`SELECT`, `WHERE`, etc).
2. With external scripts, you pass in the query, work on the results in the external language, and pass back a static result set. This means that compiled code now has to be more specialized (i.e. tightly-coupled) to the particular usage. Changing how the query uses RegEx and/or what columns are returned now requires editing, compiling, testing, and deploying the R / Python / Java code in addition to (*and* coordinated with!) the T-SQL changes.

I'm sure external scripts are absolutely wonderful, and a better choice than SQLCLR, in certain scenarios. But they certainly do not lend themselves well to the highly varied, and often ad hoc, nature of how RegEx is used (like many / most other functions).

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not have native regex support. You would need to use CLR (or as [@Lukasz Szozda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070879/lukasz-szozda) points out in the comments one of the newer [Language Extensions](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2020/04/22/open-sourcing-the-java-language-extension-for-sql-server/)) .

If I have understood the regex correctly though it matches strings of 10 digits and assigns the first 3 to group 1, second 3 to group 2, and last 4 to group 3 and then uses the back references in the expression `(\1)\2-\3`

You can use built in string functions to do this as below

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN phonenumber LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 10)
           THEN  FORMATMESSAGE('(%s)%s-%s', 
                      LEFT(phonenumber, 3),
                      SUBSTRING(phonenumber, 4, 3),
                      RIGHT(phonenumber, 4))
         ELSE phonenumber
       END
```

Comment: Still CLR? Now when we have support for [Java/R/Python](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2020/04/22/open-sourcing-the-java-language-extension-for-sql-server/) `"This extends the TSQL surface area to better handle use cases involving regular expressions, string handling, and NLP support."`

Comment: yeah, true, CLR/Other Language Extension - still nothing available out the box without having to write custom code and potentially enable additional features that are currently disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL function using CLR, that will wrap standard dotnet regex. I have wrote this and you can use it [there](https://github.com/scrappyCoco/SqlClrUtils). It will look this:

```
DECLARE @SourceText NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'My first line <br /> My second line';
DECLARE @RegexPattern NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'([<]br\s*/[>])';
DECLARE @Replacement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
DECLARE @IsCaseSensitive BIT = 0;

SELECT regex.Replace(@SourceText, @RegexPattern, @Replacement, @IsCaseSensitive);
```

Comment: Considering that the link is to a "scrappy CoCo" Github respositiory, you should be noting that you wrote it.