# sql trying to replace multiple spaces with 1 space not working

Tags: replace, ssms, space

I have a database and a certain column has multiple spaces sometimes which need to reduced to one space, like this one for example between Condo and Alki

```
West Seattle. Beach Dr. Condo  Alki Beach. Seattle
```

Now, in the beginning I had far more and I ran the following statement and got rid of them, however a couple ones like the one mentioned above do not seem to get formatted for some reason. This is the code I am using:

```
UPDATE [csv].[Listings]
SET name = REPLACE(name, '  ', ' ')
WHERE name LIKE '%  %'
```

Comment: Please, Check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql

Comment: Two things jump to mind. 1) you may need to run it repeatedly. 2) are you sure they are spaces and not some other white space like a tab

Comment: @Kevin I tried tab however, since the data I got is from airbnb, therefore might contain some special characters, I am afraid that some spaces are the characters not showing up correctly.. I have no clue what to do though..

Comment: @Kevin So I went to check the data in my original file and it seems that they are using a new line.

Comment: escape character for new line is \n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace duplicate spaces with a single space in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql)