# How to update 200000 records in mySQL with single space in name field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have more than 200000 records in my database with the customers name and information.
The customer name has much space between first name and last name.

```
ex.  1.ADAMS         CRAIG
     2. GABRIEL       GEANETTE
     3. KRANTZ        AUDREY
```

How I can remove the space in between. like

```
ex.  1.ADAMS CRAIG
     2.GABRIEL GEANETTE
     3.KRANTZ AUDREY
```

Any helps will be appreciate.

Thank You,

Comment: AFAIK: the only way to do this purely in MySQL would be to create a function that replaces multiple spaces with single spaces, and it gets ugly. Otherwise, doing a regular expression replacement in PHP would probably be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Taken from the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183056/643591)... and modified slightly to peform an update:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Name = 
        replace(
          replace(
             replace(
                LTrim(RTrim(Name)),         --Trim the field
             '  ',' |'),                    --Mark double spaces
          '| ',''),                         --Delete double spaces offset by 1
       '|','')                              --Tidy up
WHERE Name LIKE '%  %'
```

So in your example...

```
ADAMS         CRAIG
```

Would become...

```
ADAMS | | | | CRAIG
```

And once the special `|` token is removed, it becomes...

```
ADAMS CRAIG
```

And one final removal of `|` will handle even vs odd numbers of spaces.

Comment: +1 very nice, and does it all in one pass. But this assumes you know that pipes aren't included in any of the strings...  which will generally be the case

Comment: @PinnyM Yes, good point... whatever special token is used shouldn't be present in the string... you can even use a non-printable character such as `char(1)` as the token.

Comment: Does my more than 200000 records at one time... Thanks lot @MichaelFredrickson

Comment: nice idea, i was not sure it would be possible in just one pass :) +1

Comment: In a more general case, it would be nice if there was no requirement for the non-occurrence of a "special" token character within the source. It would be nice to have a solution that operated only on contiguous space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query a few times until affected rows become 0.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '))
WHERE  col LIKE '%  %'
```

Convert this query to a select query and test. If results are satisfactory, go ahead with the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select name from tmp;
+------------------------+
| name                   |
+------------------------+
| ADAMS         CRAIG    |
| GABRIEL       GEANETTE |
| KRANTZ        AUDREY   |
+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat(substr(name,1,locate(' ',name)), trim(substr(name,locate(' ', name)))) from tmp;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(substr(name,1,locate(' ',name)), trim(substr(name,locate(' ', name)))) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ADAMS CRAIG                                                                   |
| GABRIEL GEANETTE                                                              |
| KRANTZ AUDREY                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the selected answer, this statement will remove spans of contiguous space characters from a column and replace the spaces with a single space character. This operates ONLY on the space characters, and does not require any special "token" character (and does not require that the the special "token" character NOT appear within the source column.

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol =
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
         mycol
       ,SPACE(21),' ')
       ,SPACE(13),' ')
       ,SPACE(8),' ')
       ,SPACE(5),' ')
       ,SPACE(3),' ')
       ,SPACE(2),' ')
 WHERE mycol LIKE '%  %'
```

To run this expression as a test, use it in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
         mycol
       ,SPACE(21),' ')
       ,SPACE(13),' ')
       ,SPACE(8),' ')
       ,SPACE(5),' ')
       ,SPACE(3),' ')
       ,SPACE(2),' ') AS new_mycol
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.mycol LIKE '%  %'
```

This could be extended with larger spans of SPACE characters, for fewer replacements. The replacements start with the largest spans of contiguous space characters, and then the replacements are progressively smaller, to catch all of the occurrences of spaces as efficiently as possible.  (This isn't the most "efficient" algorithm, but it works suitably.)