# Remove an unknown number of Spaces from String

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Our Item Description field can have a random number of spaces between text. I use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` to clean the right and left sides of the column when pulling with SQL, but this doesn't address the unnecessary spaces between words.

I tried creating a Formula `TRIM({Command.ItemDesc})` but this has not removed the extra spaces. Is there a way to address this in Crystal or SQL 2016?

Comment: The solutions presented here are applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182877/sql-method-to-replace-repeating-blanks-with-single-blanks

Comment: Do you wish to remove *all* spaces in the middle? Or just reduce multiple chained spaces into a single space? That will affect which answers work for your case.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the number of chained spaces into a single space. So far, it seems as if all answers reduce a specific number of spaces into a single space. The problem is that the number of spaces varies from record to record.

Answer (score 2):

`TRIM` does not deal with whitespace in the middle of string, only the whitespace before and after the string, you need to use `Replace` function, try:

```
Replace({Command.ItemDesc}," ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

LONG's answer will remove *all* spaces from your string. If you wish to keep certain necessary spaces, but remove unnecessary ones, you can use this formula:

```
TRIM(Replace({Command.ItemDesc},"  "," ")
```

This formula has two steps:

1. Remove all spaces before and after the string
2. Reduce any spots with multiple spaces into one space only